# ScriptBundle says Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, scriptbundle

In the Asp.Net MVC BundleConfig if i use `ScriptBundle` it shows below error for this code:

***Code:***

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/node/GobiJs").Include(
            "~/node_modules/...../test.js"
        ));
```

***Error:***

[image]

But if i use `Bundle` instead of `ScriptBundle` like

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/node/GobiJs").Include(
                "~/node_modules/...../test.js"
            ));
```

it works fine. Can anybody tell me what's the wrong with `ScriptBundle`, why it is not working?

Comment: Difference between ScriptBundle and Bundle is ScriptBundle minifies, while Bundle does not.   I have only encountered problems with this when there is problems with the code in the JS files, which jsminify cant figure out.  So either stick with Bundle or check the js file for errors.